# Interpreting 3D parametric equations

Tags: vectors, conic-sections

I've been working through a problem and I have managed to reduce it to the following:$$x=\frac{2r}{3}\cos\theta - \frac{r}{3}\sin\theta$$ $$y=\frac{2r}{3}\sin\theta - \frac{r}{3}\cos\theta$$ $$z = -\frac{r}{3}(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)$$

I need to show this is an ellipse on the plane $x+y+z=0$ and the problem is complete. I can see this is true using software, but unfortunately I am unable to prove it algebraically.

As always, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$. Also, multiply by $3$.

Comment: I tried this approach but didn't quite manage to bring all the terms together. Will the solution be of the form $f(x,y,z) = \text{constant}$?

Comment: To show it is on the plane just add the formulas for $x,y,z$. If they sum to zero then that suffices to show the curve is on the plane. To show it is an ellipse, that depends on how you want to characterize an ellipse.

Comment: Perhaps you can also show something like $x^2+y^2=1$? (not necessarily this, but something similar) then the curve is the intersection of a cylinder and plane which you might be able to see is an ellipse?

Comment: Is there a form to have the major and minor axes stated explicitly, such that it is possible to simply read them off?

Comment: Well, in principle, an ellipse is the collection of all points for which the sum of the distances from the focal points is constant. So, if you can locate the foci and show that result in terms of vector arithmetic, I'd take that as the most satisfying answer. The coordinate system in which the ellipse takes the standard form we know from typical algebra courses will require some tinkering. That might also work.

Comment: fwiw, I derive $8x^2+8y^2+17z^2-18xz-18yz=0$ as the equation of the curve in addition to $x+y+z=0$ which does check.

Comment: Unfortunately the question also asks for the ratio of the major and minor axis. Perhaps by considering in the general case, $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ has parametric equations of the form $a\cos\theta$ and $b\sin\theta$ then the components of an arbitrary ellipse in 3d, must take the general form as above, which will then allow for the major/minor axes to be obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vector transformations:  imagine rotating the 3D ellipse onto the x-y plane.  To find the transformation, imagine rotating the normal to the x+y+z=0 plane to the z-axis.  First, rotate by $\pi/4$ about the z-axis, then rotate about the x-axis by $arctan(\sqrt{2})$.  Both of these rotations are unitary transformations, so they do not distort the ellipse.  The first rotation matrix is $U_1=\begin{pmatrix} c_1 & -s_1 & 0 \\ s_1 & c_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ where $c_1=s_1=1/\sqrt{2}$.  The second is $U_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c_2 & -s_2 \\ 0 & s_2 & c_2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ where $c_2=1/\sqrt{3}$ and $s_2=\sqrt{2/3}$. Applying the rotations to the ellipse gives
$$\begin{Bmatrix} x'\\y'\\z' \end{Bmatrix} = U_2 \cdot U_1 \begin{Bmatrix} x\\y\\ z \end{Bmatrix} = \begin{Bmatrix} (x-y)/\sqrt{2}\\(x+y-2z)/\sqrt{6}\\(x+y+z)/\sqrt{3} \end{Bmatrix} =\begin{Bmatrix} r(cos\theta -sin\theta)/\sqrt{2}\\r(cos\theta +sin\theta)/\sqrt{6}\\0 \end{Bmatrix}$$
Almost there!  All that remains is to show that $x'^2+3y'^2=r^2$, which is straight forward.

Comment: A truly beautiful application of mathematics! Ingenious method as well, may I add. Many thanks good sir!

Comment: nice work. I had used the interpretation $r^2=x^2+y^2$, but, it seems $r$ was a constant.

Comment: @James Yes, I almost made the $x=r cos\theta$ substitution, but realized that that $\theta$ was a parameter.  I wanted to change it $t$, or something, because using $\theta$ in this context throws off my intuition.  And the same the $r$.